# How copy line from a txt list and paste it in another txt at specific number line using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm relatively new to PowerShell. I would like to be able to copy a text line from a list file and paste it on another text file at specific number line.

I have the first step and need help the next instructions:

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\Megateo\Hash.txt -TotalCount 121 | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1 > C:\Temp\Megateo\Monin.txt
```

Comment: load the 2nd file into a generic.list and use the `.Insert()` method to insert the found line into the target collection ... then save that to your file.

Comment: Thanks for help Lee, can you explain me with an example

Comment: do you want to insert the source line before, after, OR in place of the target line in the 2nd file?

Comment: I want replace  in the 2nd file

Comment: kool! [*grin*] that is actually easier ... no need for any fancy collection. please let me know if you have any questions about the Answer i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one way to do the job. since you want to *replace* the target line, there is no need for anything more than a standard array. no insert, just replace. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$FirstFile = "$env:TEMP\FirstFile.txt"
$SecondFile = "$env:TEMP\SecondFile.txt"
$ThirdFile = "$env:TEMP\ThirdFile.txt"

#region "make files to work with"
# remove this entire "#region/#endregion" block when you are ready to work with your real data

# make a "first file" to work with
1..66 |
    ForEach-Object {
        '{0} is the 1st file line number' -f $_
        } |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $FirstFile -Force

# make a "second file" to work with
1..66 |
    ForEach-Object {
        '--- {0} is the 2nd file line number ---' -f $_
        } |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $SecondFile -Force
#endregion "make files to work with"

$1stFileSourceLine = 33
$2ndFileDestLine = 11
#$2ndFileDestLine = 17
#$2ndFileDestLine = 22

# the "-1" is because collections start at zero
$LineFromFirstFile = (Get-Content -LiteralPath $FirstFile)[$1stFileSourceLine - 1]
$SecondFile_Content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $SecondFile

$SecondFile_Content[$2ndFileDestLine - 1] = $LineFromFirstFile

Set-Content -LiteralPath $ThirdFile -Value $SecondFile_Content -Force
```

truncated content of the `$ThirdFile` ...

```
[*...snip...*] 

--- 6 is the 2nd file line number ---
--- 7 is the 2nd file line number ---
--- 8 is the 2nd file line number ---
--- 9 is the 2nd file line number ---
--- 10 is the 2nd file line number ---
33 is the 1st file line number
--- 12 is the 2nd file line number ---
--- 13 is the 2nd file line number ---
--- 14 is the 2nd file line number ---
--- 15 is the 2nd file line number ---
--- 16 is the 2nd file line number ---

[*...snip...*]
```

what the code does ...

- sets the file locations & names
- creates the 1st and 2nd files
  that is wrapped in `#region/#endregion` markers. just remove that AFTER you have confirmed that the code works as expected.
- sets the source file line to copy
- sets the destination file line to replace
  the two commented out lines are alternate values to make double sure that it was doing what i thot it was doing. [*grin*]
- reads the 1st file & grabs the source file line
  as the comment points out, the index numbers are off by one - and the code corrects for that by subtracting 1.
- reads in the 2nd file
- replaces the target line of the 2nd file with the source line from the 1st file
- sends the resulting modified file content to the `$ThirdFile`
  it's generally a bad idea to overwrite one of the working files. so i had the modified content sent to a 3rd file.

Comment: thank you very much Lee

Comment: @JuanCamiloCometa - you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]